# How to display en error message when validation fails in PHP Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I'm stuck in displaying a message in form validation.

Here is my code:

```
class InputController extends Controller
{
    public static function save(Request $request)
    {
        //Get input values to variables respectively
        $First_Name = $request->input('First_Name');
        $Last_Name = $request->input('Last_Name');
        $Email = $request->input('Email');
        $Credit_Card = $request->input('Credit_Card');
        $Password = $request->input('Password');

        //Rules for each field
        $rules = [
            'First_Name' => ['required', 'string'],
            'Last_Name' => ['required', 'string'],
            'Email' => ['required', 'string'],
            'Credit_Card' => ['required', 'string'],
            'Password' => ['required', 'string']
        ];

        //Validator variable
        $valid = Validator::make($request->all(),$rules);

        //Insert information into SQL table
        $customer = new CustomersTable;
        $customer->First_Name = $First_Name;
        $customer->Last_Name = $Last_Name;
        $customer->Email = $Email;
        $customer->Credit_Card = $Credit_Card;
        $customer->Password = Hash::make($Password);

        $customer->save();

        //If validation fails, pop out a message or else view localhost/submit
        if ($valid -> failed())
        {
            dd("Error! Some of the required information are empty");
        }
        else
        {
            return view('submit');
        }
    }
}
```

In the below:

```
if ($valid -> failed())
{
    dd("Error! Some of the required information are empty");
}
else
{
    return view('submit');
}
```

,when I let every field (First_Name, Last_Name,...) in the form empty and click the button to post, the validation should be fail and the page should display

```
"Error! Some of the required information are empty"
```

But instead, it pops out the error of SQL:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'First_Name' cannot be null
```

, which means it jumped into "else" statement.
Can anyone explain it for me?

Comment: Would the documentation on [Displaying The Validation Errors](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors) help?

Comment: read this link

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59806074/why-is-my-validator-is-not-validating-in-laravel/59806173#59806173

Comment: @brombeer Is there any other way?

Comment: @brombeer   see link

Comment: @sajjad Still didn't work for me.

Comment: view to sample code @HackerRhino
attention to $valid->fails()

Answer (score 2):

you have to put this code before you insert the data

```
if ($valid -> failed())
{
    dd("Error! Some of the required information are empty");
}
```

your code should be

```
//Validator variable
    $valid = Validator::make($request->all(),$rules);
    if ($valid -> failed())
    {
        dd("Error! Some of the required information are empty");
    }
    else
    {
        //Get input values to variables respectively
        $First_Name = $request->input('First_Name');
        $Last_Name = $request->input('Last_Name');
        $Email = $request->input('Email');
        $Credit_Card = $request->input('Credit_Card');
        $Password = $request->input('Password');

        //Insert information into SQL table
        $customer = new CustomersTable;
        $customer->First_Name = $First_Name;
        $customer->Last_Name = $Last_Name;
        $customer->Email = $Email;
        $customer->Credit_Card = $Credit_Card;
        $customer->Password = Hash::make($Password);

        $customer->save();
        return view('submit');
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because of you are assigning request values to variables before validation. Try this:

```
class InputController extends Controller
{
    public static function save(Request $request)
    {
       
        $request->validate([
            'First_Name' => ['required', 'string'],
            'Last_Name' => ['required', 'string'],
            'Email' => ['required', 'string'],
            'Credit_Card' => ['required', 'string'],
            'Password' => ['required', 'string']
        ]);


        //Get input values to variables respectively
        $First_Name = $request->input('First_Name');
        $Last_Name = $request->input('Last_Name');
        $Email = $request->input('Email');
        $Credit_Card = $request->input('Credit_Card');
        $Password = $request->input('Password');

        //Insert information into SQL table
        $customer = new CustomersTable;
        $customer->First_Name = $First_Name;
        $customer->Last_Name = $Last_Name;
        $customer->Email = $Email;
        $customer->Credit_Card = $Credit_Card;
        $customer->Password = Hash::make($Password);

        $customer->save();

        //If validation fails, pop out a message or else view localhost/submit
        if ($valid -> failed())
        {
            dd("Error! Some of the required information are empty");
        }
        else
        {
            return view('submit');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if you wanna show the error messages in form you can do this by blade @error component, so if validation fails user redirects to submit view with errors shown.

Comment: I thought there is a 'require' property in $rules so when letting all fields empty, the validation should always fail?

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($valid->fails())
{
   return redirect()->back()->withErrors($valid)->withInput();
}
```

and in blade template show errors with below code

```
@if ($errors->has('First_Name'))
    <span class="invalid-feedback">
        <strong>{{ $errors->first('First_Name') }}</strong>
    </span>
@endif
```